# ClusterManager in GoogleMap android

Tags: android, maps, markerclusterer

I want to implement marker clustering on Google Map. It should involve custom rendering too. So I used sample code from https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils,

Referring to the CustomMarkerClusteringDemoActivity.java from the demo.

**My problem is When I click on the cluster it does not call onClusterClick().Similarly on clicking on cluster item, onClusterItemClick() does not get called.**

I can't understand where I going wrong, Please  help....

I am using :

**Step 1:**

```
private ClusterManager<MarkerCluster> mClusterManager;
```

**Step 2:**

```
private class MarkerRenderer extends DefaultClusterRenderer<MarkerCluster> {

    private final IconGenerator mIconGenerator = 
        new IconGenerator(context.getApplicationContext());
    private final IconGenerator mClusterIconGenerator = 
        new IconGenerator(context.getApplicationContext());
    private final ImageView mImageView = null;
    private final TextView mClusterTextCounter;
    private final ImageView mClusterImageView;
    private final int mDimension = 0;

    public MarkerRenderer() {
        super(context.getApplicationContext(), mMap, mClusterManager);

        View multiProfile = getActivity().getLayoutInflater()
            .inflate(R.layout.layout_marker_render, null);
        mClusterIconGenerator.setContentView(multiProfile);
        mClusterImageView = (ImageView)multiProfile
            .findViewById(R.id.lyt_marker_render_img_pin);
        mClusterTextCounter = (TextView) multiProfile
            .findViewById(R.id.lyt_marker_render_txt_counter);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onBeforeClusterItemRendered(MarkerCluster markercluster, MarkerOptions markerOptions) {
        // Draw a single person.
        // Set the info window to show their name.
        Item mItem = markercluster.getItem();

        if(mItem != null){

            if(mItem.get_UserType().equalsIgnoreCase("2")){
                markerOptions
                    .title(mItem.get_maker() + " - " + mItem.get_carModel())
                    .icon(icon_blue);
            }else{
                markerOptions
                    .title(mItem.get_maker() + " - " + mItem.get_carModel())
                    .icon(icon_gray);
            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBeforeClusterRendered(Cluster<MarkerCluster> cluster, MarkerOptions markerOptions) {
        // Draw multiple people.
        // Note: this method runs on the UI thread. Don't spend too much time in here (like in this example).
        mClusterTextCounter.setText(cluster.getItems().size() + "");

        Drawable myDrawable;
        if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
            myDrawable = context.getResources()
                .getDrawable(R.drawable.pin_blue, context.getTheme());
        } else {
            myDrawable = context.getResources()
                .getDrawable(R.drawable.pin_blue);
        }

        mClusterImageView.setImageDrawable(myDrawable);

        mClusterIconGenerator.setBackground(
            context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.map_btn)
        );

        Bitmap icon = mClusterIconGenerator.makeIcon(
            String.valueOf(cluster.getSize())
        );

        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(icon));
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean shouldRenderAsCluster(Cluster cluster) {
        // Always render clusters.
        return cluster.getSize() > 1;
    }
}
```

**Step 3:**

```
mClusterManager = new ClusterManager<MarkerCluster>(context, mMap);
mClusterManager.setRenderer(new MarkerRenderer());

mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager);
mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(mClusterManager);
mMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {

        if (mClusterManager != null) {
            mClusterManager.onCameraChange(cameraPosition);
        }

        // Some Other Tasks here

    }
});

mClusterManager.setOnClusterClickListener(
    new ClusterManager.OnClusterClickListener<MarkerCluster>() {
        @Override
        public boolean onClusterClick(Cluster<MarkerCluster> cluster) {
            LatLngBounds.Builder builder = LatLngBounds.builder();
            for (MarkerCluster item : cluster.getItems()) {
                builder.include(item.getPosition());
            }
            final LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 100));

            return true;
    }
});


mClusterManager.setOnClusterItemClickListener(
    new ClusterManager.OnClusterItemClickListener<MarkerCluster>() {
        @Override
        public boolean onClusterItemClick(MarkerCluster markerCluster) {

            Item item = markerCluster.getItem();
            if (mItem != null) {

                MarkerClickDialog mMarkerClickDialog = new MarkerClickDialog(context, mItem);
                mMarkerClickDialog.show();
        }

        return false;
    }
});

for (int i = 0; i < mItemList.size(); i++) {

    Item mItem = mItemList.get(i);
    if (mMap != null) {
        displayLocation(
            Double.parseDouble(mItem.get_Latitude()),
            Double.parseDouble(mItem.get_Longitude()), 
            mItem
        );
    }
}

private void displayLocation(double latitude, double longitude, Item mItem){

    // create marker
    if(mMap != null){
        Marker mMarker = null;

        MarkerCluster offsetItem = new MarkerCluster(new LatLng(latitude, longitude), "Test", R.drawable.pin_blue, mItem);
        mClusterManager.addItem(offsetItem);
        mClusterManager.cluster();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `MarkerRenderer` constructor, there is `super(context.getApplicationContext(), mMap, mClusterManager);`

You still need your GoogleMap object and ClusterManager. You should pass parameters to the constructor! Write like this:

```
public CustomRenderer(Context context, GoogleMap map, ClusterManager clusterManager) {
    super(context, map, clusterManager);
    ...
```

And when you set Renderer, write like this

```
mClusterManager.setRenderer(new MarkerRenderer(mContext, mMap, mClusterManager));
```